# Guzzle error "Call to a member function getStatusCode() on null" when curl and Postman are perfectly fine

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, guzzle6

I'm setting up Guzzle as my Laravel 6's HTTP Client in my project. It was perfectly working and giving responses on every API hit. But suddenly it returns "Call to a member function getStatusCode() on null" error.

I've tried using Postman and curl to hit the API, and they return the right response when Guzzle not.

Instead of returning response, the print_r for RequestException response's return null.

I've **tried to debug** the REST API to test where the request go when hitting it using Guzzle, and the **request didn't even hit to the destination function**.

Here's my Guzzle code:

```php
class ApiCallback
{
    public static function request($method, $uri, $params = [], $useAccessToken = true){
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = null;

        $jsonObj = null;
        try{
            if($useAccessToken){
                $response = $client->request(
                    strtoupper($method),
                    $uri,
                    [
                        "headers" =>[
                            'Accept' => '*/*',
                            "Authorization" => "Bearer ".Session::get('access_token'),
                            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                            'User-Agent' => 'saranaku-'.Session::get('id'),
                            'Content-Length' => '0',
                            'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
                            'Connection' => 'keep-alive'
                        ]
                        ,
                        "body" => \json_encode(
                            $params
                        )
                    ]
                );
            }else{
                $response = $client->request(
                    strtoupper($method),
                    $uri,
                    [
                        "headers" =>[
                            'Accept' => '*/*',
                            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                            'User-Agent' => "saranaku-guest",
                            'Content-Length' => '0',
                            'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
                            'Connection' => 'keep-alive'
                        ]
                        ,
                        "body" => \json_encode(
                            $params
                        )
                    ]
                );
            }
            $jsonObj = json_decode((string) $response->getBody());
            return new BaseResponse(
                $jsonObj->status ?? false,
                $jsonObj->code ?? null,
                $jsonObj->message ?? null ,
                $jsonObj->data ?? null
            );
        }catch(RequestException $e){
//            echo Psr7\str($e->getRequest());
//            echo Psr7\str($e->getResponse());
            $jsonObj = $e->getResponse();
            print_r($e->getResponse());
        }
        return new BaseResponse(
            $jsonObj->status ?? false,
            $jsonObj->getStatusCode() ?? null,
            $jsonObj->getReasonPhrase() ?? null ,
            $jsonObj->data ?? null
        );
    }

    public static function requestWithoutAccessToken($method, $url, $params = []){
        return ApiCallback::request($method, $url, $params, false);
    }
}

final class BaseResponse
{
    public $status;
    public $code;
    public $message;
    public $data;

    public function __construct($status,$code,$message = "",$data = [])
    {
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->code = $code;
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}
```

Additional information:

1. The REST API is running in localhost with endpoint: /v1/login
2. The HTTP method is POST
3. The REST API is using Java Spring Boot v1.5.6
4. The Request Body is

```
{
     "data":{
          "username": "username_string",
          "password": "password_string"
     }
}
```

5. I've tried these clearing caches, and doing `composer dump-autoload` and the problem still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and the solution.

So I'm doing some Logging on the exception with  `Log` and found out that my `$uri` is not valid due my API BASE URL was not found on `.env` file. So the solution is doing `php artisan cache:clear` and the guzzle works.

For anyone who reading this question, please remember to try `Log` if the stack trace didn't help you out.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was an incorrectly configured error logging remote channel. The error happens on error channel failure, not in your code.

As you mentioned, must either fix the error logging or check logs on server, they have have the original error stack.